# wcf client reporting SSL exception only on one occasion

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl

Our WCF client normally invokes a web service. All deployments of the client invoke the same web service. In most deployments it makes the call without any issues, except in one instance it reports the following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

What could be different with this one installation?

We tested the URL that the client uses to make the call to the web service in the browser. The web service returns a response ok in Firefox but not in IE.

Comment: Could be a corrupt certificate store, or something like that.

Comment: A corrupt certificate store on the windows machine hosting the wcf client?  What's the best course of action to correct it?

Comment: A first step would be to delete, then re-install the certificate(s). What error does IE show?

Comment: What are the deployments? Are the machines the same? Where are they? Could you check proxy settings? Could you ensure that time is syncronised on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - there was a new web service server certificate installed with SHA256 and Windows 2003 Server requires a hotfix to support it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this article yet? It contains fairly good tips for troubleshooting these issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx?Redirected=true

For example, you'll need to check that the particular machine has all the root and intermediate certificates properly deployed.